# Where can I find 6 DOF manipulator packages for gazebo?

Tags: ros, manipulator, mobile-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. Where can I find 6 DOF manipulator with a 4-wheel mobile base packages for gazebo?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412513/where-can-i-find-6-dof-manipulator-packages-for-gazebo?/) by [NickRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/56714/nickros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use,

Kuka Youbot,

https://github.com/ctruillet/youbot_description

or you can use URDf and links from this https://github.com/zyjiao4728/Planning-on-VKC

note on this you have to convert the Ros code to ROS2.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0